# IIS ARR - Is it possible forward/stream post request as is without buffering or adding headers

Tags: iis, streaming, arr

I'm trying to implement WebSocket type of functionality, but using only plain http. So there's a connection over GET that gets data from server, and a connection with POST that sends data to server. Both connections send/receive streaming data, and use content length = 1 GB, type = application octet stream. The two connections remain open till the server sends an "end" command over the GET connection.

Without ARR things work (the back-end server is not IIS).

I added ARR to the setup, did all the configuration steps (including response buffer threshold = 0, max request size = 2GB). Hitting normal urls, submitting forms from browser over ARR works perfectly.

However the POST connection to send data to server does not work. The client sends the data, but the back-end server does not get anything (verified using wireshark). It remains hung for a while, if I terminate the client then ARR failure trace log is generated, and it shows 400 error response, this seems to be because the actual amount of data was not 1 GB in length.

The GET connection works. (If I point the POST connection to directly talk to the back-end server, things work)

So my question is: Is it possible to send streaming data as POST request via ARR? Any suggestions on how to achieve it?

Thanks